# form fields under fixed footer navbar have higher click priority like navbar items

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have long page with select boxes and input fields and fixed navbar with icons (footer menu). In the case when user clicks on navbar item and select box is under navbar - select box expands and reacts on click - navbar doesnt reacts.
Every answer will be very appreciated.

Sample of code:

```
<div data-role="content">   
        <form id="profileForm">
<label for="sex">Pohlavie:</label>
            <select name="sex" id="sex" data-theme="a" onchange="check_profile_form()">
               <option value="0" placeholder></option>
               <option value="1">žena</option>
               <option value="2">muž</option>
            </select>
</form> 
    </div>    
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-toggle="false">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="c">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="c"><img src="img/ikony_05.png" class="footer_image" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="c"><img src="img/ikony_06.png" class="footer_image" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"><img src="img/ikony_07.png" class="footer_image" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="c"><img src="img/ikony_08.png" class="footer_image" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image: mobile app screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal javascript behavior.

There is no such thing as a higher click priority like navbar items.

In your case, when a header with a navbar is fixed and has a full-screen attribute turned on page header will cover part of page content. When click event is triggered of a navbar tab that same event will propagate to all elements found below (in your case it is a select box).

To prevent this you should bound your own click event on a navbar li elements (like you probably do because you have href="#") and inside your click event, use this:

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

More about this can be found here;:

- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Xz2np/, click on a blue box to see a difference.

Comment: Hi Gajotres! At first thanks for fast reply. I don't think that this behaviour is standard, because when I have tested it on Chrome with Ripple emulator everything worked well. It looks like Android behaviour. I also tried your advice but it didn't work for me... I made a screenshot of application, could you please take a look on it and let me know if you understood my problem good way? Thanks

Comment: I tried this $('a.profile').click(function() { $.mobile.changePage($("#profile")); event.stopPropagation();});  but it changed my page to #main and did nothing. Event stopImmediatePropagation() did not nothing.

Comment: I need to say, if is navbar item clicked and selectbox is under item, any command inside $('a.profile').click(function() {}); is executed (only selectbox expands). Btw options in selectboxes are native.